# The UseSWR hook not working in nextjs component

Tags: next.js, swr

I am trying to use the useSWR hook to fetch data from an API.

The API and requests works fine but the data is never updating.
Here is the code:

```
import useSWR from 'swr'
import { SERVER_URL } from '../config';
import axios from 'axios'

const fetcher = url => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)

export default function MainPageView() {

  const { routines, error } = useSWR(`${SERVER_URL}/api/routines`, fetcher, { refreshInterval: 1000 })

  return (...The rest of the component)
```

When using the `routines` inside I call it like that `{routines?routines:[]}`

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english :)

Edited:
I will also mention that if i inspect the page with F12 and go to the network tab, I do see the requests being sent and received with the desired data (**with response STATUS 304**) but it never updates the `routines` variable.

Comment: Try using `const { data: routines, error } = useSWR(...)`, the data returned by the `fetcher` function is available in the `data` property.

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you it worked !! :)
I will add an answer with your comment and credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using const { data: routines, error } = useSWR(...), the data returned by the fetcher function is available in the data property

The answer was given by [juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves)

Answer (score 0):

`useSWR` hook returns 3 states **data**, **loading** and **error**

try something like this

```
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`${SERVER_URL}/api/routines`, fetcher, { refreshInterval: 1000 })
```

using data

```
{data?.properties?.map((item)=>...) }
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( The error is `Cannot read property 'routines' of undefined`

Comment: @GuyMayo I made change